# Drupal Domain Access module Settings Tab White Screen of Death WSOD

Tags: drupal-7, wsod, drupal-domain-access

In the Drupal 7.x project I'm developing, I'm using Domain Access module.
Somehow, when I try to access the Settings tab (admin/structure/domain/settings) I get a WSOD.

ERROR LOG:

[Wed May 07 11:20:08 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function object_log() in /var/www/MYDRUPALPROJECT/sites/all/modules/custom/domain_bonus/domain_bonus_login_restrict/domain_bonus_login_restrict.module on line 55, referer: http:// MYDRUPALPROJECT/en/admin/structure/domain

Content from the file in question:

......

/**

*Implements hook_form_alter().

*/

function domain_bonus_login_restrict_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

```
switch ($form_id) {

 .....

 // Provide option to enable / disable restriction on domain settings form.

 case 'domain_configure_form':

    (LINE 55:)      object_log('form_id ' . time(), $form_id);

 .....
```

This custom module is a copy of the contrib module with just some simple modifications that don't involve the line in question.

Anyone have any idea what can be the cause of this?
Should I share any other relevant information to help you understand this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

The problem was that the contrib module Domain Bonus: Login Restrict comes with the following lines of code:

object_log('form_id ' . time(), $form_id);

object_log('form_state ' . time(), $form_state);

object_log('form ' . time(), $form);

Those lines are used to debbug, probably during the module development.

object_log() function is a function from the object log module that can be used to debbug, more specifically to check variables value in a specific part of the code.

Since in the module .info file isn't defined that the Domain Bonus: Login Restrict module depends on the Object Log module, the Object Log module wasn't even installed in our project... In that conditions when reading that line, Drupal crashes.

So, for this function to work Object Log module needs to be installed, this module needs Devel module to work. Or simply just comment or delete those lines.

Cheers.